# Erlang. Can somebody explain me the behavior of the list of function?

Tags: erlang

When I create a list like this:

```
 LF1 =  [fun(X)->X*Y end || Y <- lists:seq(1,10)].
```

I receive

```
[#Fun<erl_eval.6.52032458>,#Fun<erl_eval.6.52032458>,
#Fun<erl_eval.6.52032458>,#Fun<erl_eval.6.52032458>,
#Fun<erl_eval.6.52032458>,#Fun<erl_eval.6.52032458>,
#Fun<erl_eval.6.52032458>,#Fun<erl_eval.6.52032458>,
#Fun<erl_eval.6.52032458>,#Fun<erl_eval.6.52032458>]
```

Then, when I use it like this:

```
[F(3) || F <- LF1].
```

I receive the result as it mentioned:

```
[3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30]
```

But, when I spawn all that functions from list:

```
LPF = [spawn(fun()->F(3) end) || F <- LF1].

[<0.1424.0>,<0.1425.0>,<0.1426.0>,<0.1427.0>,<0.1428.0>,
     <0.1429.0>,<0.1430.0>,<0.1431.0>,<0.1432.0>,<0.1433.0>]
```

And then send them the parameter:

```
[X ! 3 || X <- LPF].
```

I receive:

```
[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I found my mistake:

```
[spawn(fun()->io:format("~p~n", [F(3)]) end) || F <- LF1].
3
6
9
12
15
18
21
24
27
30
[<0.1460.0>,<0.1461.0>,<0.1462.0>,<0.1463.0>,<0.1464.0>,
<0.1465.0>,<0.1466.0>,<0.1467.0>,<0.1468.0>,<0.1469.0>]
```

Sending a message was wrong method.

Comment: Yeah, so the principle is: `!` returns the right hand side (or an error).  See [send](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#send).